# can't extend NSData with Value Type

Tags: swift2, sqlite.swift

this section doesn't work with swift2 branch:

https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/swift-2/Documentation/Index.md#binary-data

I get:

`Redundant conformance of 'NSData' to protocol 'Value'`

and

`Type 'UIImage' does not conform to protocol 'Value'`

Comment: The `swift-2` branch (for now) already implements conformance with NSData, so you shouldn't need to implement the extension yourself anymore!

Comment: Thanks Stephen, still have problem extending UIImage. Also in swift-2 branch it looks like db.userVersion is not available anymore, is there a way to track db version?

Comment: Check out the extension here for a workaround: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/issues/194 A new pragma interface is coming in a future version. What does your UIImage extension look like?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the code from your documentation example

```
extension NSData: Value {
class var declaredDatatype: String {
    return Blob.declaredDatatype
}
class func fromDatatypeValue(blobValue: Blob) -> Self {
    return self(bytes: blobValue.bytes, length: blobValue.length)
}
var datatypeValue: Blob {
    return Blob(bytes: bytes, length: length)
}
```

}